# Getting font metrics in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts

I'm currently working on a JavaScript project that uses the HTML5 canvas as a rendering target.  In order for my code to play nicely with the (rigidly specified) interfaces I've been provided, I need to be able to take a font and extract the ascent and descent heights of that font.  This will allow clients to more accurately position the text.  I'm aware that I can change where the text draws by setting the `textBaseline` attribute, but I actually need the numeric values describing these different heights.  Is there a simple way to do this?  If not, is there a (hopefully lightweight) library that can handle it for me?  Most of the proposed solutions I've found are heavyweight font rendering libraries, which seems like massive overkill for this problem.

Comment: Mozillas Bespin tried to solve that problem and finally run into argument which ended with the conclusion canvas was and will never be designed for text editors. So either rely on 'm' having same height and width or use the source of Bespin or the pixel test method described below or measure an off div with same text/font or any other unreliable approximation.

Sorry, don't like disillusion, too. But are you sure you chose the right horse for this path?

Comment: I'm currently working on an implementation of the JVM in JavaScript and am using the canvas as a rendering target.  I need to implement the Java font libraries, which is why I need these precise values.  I'm thinking that I'm going to go with Simon's answer and just fake up the implementation by writing offscreen and pixel-scraping the results back. :-(

Comment: I hope, you have considered font smoothing....

Comment: @templatetypedef Is it too late to answer this? I have the solution. `ctx.measureText("text").width`. I think that's right. I'll double check it if you still need it.

Comment: @Ryan Amos- I'm aware of this solution, but it only computes the width of the text, not the height, font ascent, or font descent, which are the values that I actually needed.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm pretty sure .height will give you the height. As for the others, I don't know what they are or if that will retrieve them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](https://galacticmilk.com/journal/2011/01/html5-typographic-metrics/) on HTML5 Typographic Metrics discusses the problem and a [part solution using CSS](https://galacticmilk.com/journal/2011/01/html5-typographic-metrics/#baselineCSS) - although the integer rounding of offsetTop etc is a problem (potentially can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get proper floating point values for some browsers).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that there is no built in way and you are sort-of on your own.

Because of this, most people simply estimate them. Some people pre-calculate all the values, which isn't too much work provided you are using only a few fonts.

The third way is to make a canvas in memory and print some letters (say, a `Q` and an `O`) and programatically attempt to determine the ascent and descent using per-pixel collision. It's a pain and can be slow depending on the number of fonts and how accurate you want to be, but it is the most accurate way of going about it if you do not want to pre-compute the values.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference here:
The width of the text can be measured with:

```
ctx.measureText(txt).width
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp