# Function that return the part of a div that overflowed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div that contains a long text, including other HTML markup (`<h1>`, `<b>`, etc). The div has the following css rule:

```
height: 100px; overflow: hidden;
```

Is there a jQuery function that gives me the part of the text that is overflowing the specified div bounds, so that I can append it to another div?

Comment: Nice question. But I don't think that's possible. `:(` Different browsers have different font implementation based on the viewport size.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you. Lets assume we use times new roman thats is cross browser solution

Comment: @Wermerb Man... Not sure. No way. `:P`

Comment: @JTC Thank you, its a nice function but i need that part what is overflown to be able to append to an other div

Comment: Check out this question, I think that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400174/continuing-overflowed-text-in-a-different-div

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder Thank you it helped me a lot. Its solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of characters that fit on a line and also easily calculate the number of lines that fit in the div (just devide the height by the font-size i think), check out this answer here -> [How to count number of characters in a line using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113874/how-to-count-number-of-characters-in-a-line-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will be interesting :D.
[CSS3 multicolumn](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)