# How can I select individual line and character in paragraph like nth-child(n) in css using css or javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Character count in a line will vary with respect to device size.

I need to know number of characters in a line.
How to select nth-line like selecting nth-child(n) in css?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Title Page</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                *{
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113874/how-to-count-number-of-characters-in-a-line-using-javascript

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113874/how-to-count-number-of-characters-in-a-line-using-javascript