# How to get count of characters before paragraph wraps into next line?

Tags: javascript, text

I'm trying to count how many characters are displayed in the **first line** of a text which is wrapped because the width of the span is limited.

I know that counting the characters of a String can be done with "length", but I'm failing to get the first line.

Example:

```css
#divone {
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="divone">
  <p id="one">Some long text
    <p>
</div>
```

Displayed the text appears as first line: "some long" and second line "text"

Expected output from JavaScript:

```
Some long
```

Pseudocode I thought to solve it:

1. Detect which is the last word before the text is wrapped
2. Look this word up in original text and retrieve a substring
3. Use `length()` to count characters of the substring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count number of characters in a line using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113874/how-to-count-number-of-characters-in-a-line-using-javascript)

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of knowing the length of the first line ? Is it to hide the rest of the text, or to process it?

Comment: @Lucio , I want to process it - I need to compare different Interfaces which are different in size of the div's and therefore I need a parameter which is "maximal charachters per line displayed on UI"

Comment: @Mohammad, thanks - worked with a few changes on the code!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments I found I solution which is approx. what I want:

[How to count number of characters in a line using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113874/how-to-count-number-of-characters-in-a-line-using-javascript)